# How can i read files from src/main/resources with the java.io.File class?

Tags: java, maven, weka

I have a maven project that has resources packaged inside src/main/resources. That dependency uses the weka library, specifically the [AddClassification class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/AddClassification.java?av=f) that in its `AddClassification.setOptions()` method uses the `java.io.FILE` class to read a given model file.
Maybe its also important to notice that this project is a dependency of other maven projects and that in the end it will be used by a web app application running inside apache-tomcat.

For clarification the method `AddClassification.setOptions()` is called like this:

```
AddClassification filter = new AddClassification();
filter.setInputFormat(labeled);
String[] options = new String[3];
options[0] = "-serialized";
options[1] = "models/trained.model";
options[2] = "-classification";
filter.setOptions(options);
```

**So, down to my problems and needs:**

- I need to pass a file path string to the `AddClassification.setOptions()`;
- I need to use the weka library as this little dependency wasn't codded by myself;
- All model files should be inside the Jar file (src/main/resources) to allow convenient distribution;
- `java.io.File` won't read files inside the Jar file directly *(i have looked it up)*;
- I know that `class.getResourceAsStream` would solve the problem nicely but the weka library wants a String parameter to use `java.io.File`.

How can i solve the problem? I could easily copy all resources to a hardcoded system directory but that would make my project a pain to distribute to other systems.
I'm looking for a correct way to solve the problem.

I hope that i made myself clear enough.

Comment: you can't, libraries that rely on implementations like this are poorly written and designed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the code the simplest way I can see to achieve it would be to subclass `AddClassification` and override the protected `getActualClassifier` method to load your classifier from a `getResourceAsStream`.  Annoyingly you still have to ensure that you pass a path to a file that definitely exists to `setOptions` otherwise it'll complain, but you may be able to get away with something like `/dev/null` or `/bin/sh` as you don't need to actually *read* from the file, it just has to exist.

```
AddClassification filter = new AddClassification() {
  protected Classifier getActualClassifier() {
    ObjectInputStream   ois;

    if (m_ActualClassifier == null) {
      try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                     this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("classifier.ser"));
        m_ActualClassifier = (Classifier) ois.readObject();
        m_SerializedHeader = null;
        // let's see whether there's an Instances header stored as well
        try {
          m_SerializedHeader = (Instances) ois.readObject();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // ignored
          m_SerializedHeader = null;
        }
        ois.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        m_ActualClassifier = null;
        System.err.println("Failed to instantiate classifier:");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    return m_ActualClassifier;
  }
};

filter.setInputFormat(labeled);
String[] options = new String[3];
options[0] = "-serialized";
options[1] = "/dev/null";
options[2] = "-classification";
filter.setOptions(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always copy your resource to a temporary file:

```
Path file = Files.createTempFile(null, null);

try (InputStream stream =
    MyOwnClass.class.getResourceAsStream("models/trained.model")) {

    Files.copy(stream, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

options[1] = file.toString();
```

Answer (score -2):

Please just try that

```
AddClassification filter = new AddClassification();
filter.setInputFormat(labeled);
String[] options = new String[3];
options[0] = "-serialized";
options[1] =  this.getClass().getResource("/models/trained.model").getFile();
options[2] = "-classification";
filter.setOptions(options);
```

Comment: URL.getFile() *does not* return a file name. It returns the path portion of a URL, which might contain escaped octets and therefore is not guaranteed to correspond to an existing file path. The method is named getFile() because the URL class is very old, part of Java 1.0 in fact, and back then, URLs frequently referred to physical files (such as in ftp: URLs). Compare `new URL("file:/C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft")` with `new File("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft")`.